# How can I develop on a cloud using eclipse?

Tags: java, android, eclipse, cloud

I want to be able to access my code from any computer on eclipse. is it possible?

edit: i am developing for android using java

Comment: @tuğrulbüyükışık i want the code to be stored on the cloud so i can access it from any where as long as i have eclipse installed

Comment: @SpK Yes. its not really what i am looking for. i want something like how you can access your personal bookmarks, settings etc on any chrome browser

Answer (score 1):

I just keep my Workspaces inside Dropbox along side my normal process of backing up via Mercurial to an offsite service. Has worked well for me.

You could easily replace Dropbox and Mercurial with any one of the many free alternatives.

Answer (score 1):

A professinal solution would be using an Source Code Control System like Subversion, CVS or Git. There are several distributers where you can get such repositorys for free.
A definitly not professinal solution, but much less complex, so this might even be better for you, is to host your eclipse Projects in something like DropBox/Google Drive/Skydrive whatever.

Since you said, you want to have the ability to work on your code from all your devices, but not that there are severel people working on the code at the same time, i would propose keeping your projects in something like DropBox, since its really really easier and less complex.
When it might happen to you that several people will work on the source, you need a professional solution. For nearly all these professional solution are eclipse plugins available, so you can update/commit/merge your code out of eclipse.

Answer (score 0):

Try a [Source Control Management](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Source_Control_Management) system. You'll find several plugins for Eclipse, for example [EGit](http://marketplace.eclipse.org/content/egit-git-team-provider) in combination with [GitHub](https://github.com/)

Answer (score 0):

Although it's much *easier* to setup a cloud service account and a folder that is synced between your computers it's much *better* to use a [Source control management](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Source_Control_Management) [system](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_revision_control_software) like [Git](http://git-scm.com/). The reason for this is that the SCM systems provide history of your development with messages for every [commited](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Commit_%28data_management%29#Revision_control) change, you can see differences between your changes and many more.

According to your comment:

> i want something like how you can access your personal bookmarks, settings etc on any chrome browser

you might be looking to sync your eclipse and workspace directories via any cloud service of your choice.